# Google Earth KML touring speed

Tags: kml, google-earth

I'we created KML tours that can be played in Google Earth and I'm wondering if there is any option to define the speed at which the tour is being played ... not the speed of the transition between points but the actual play speed - i.e. defining a high value would make the tour look like it's in a fast forward mode while defining a low(er) value would make the tour play very slowly.

Thanks

Comment: Are you generating the KML Tour yourself (writing the KML manually or programmatically), or are you using Google Earth to create a tour for you?

Comment: Generating the KML file using micromata's Java API for KML.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, you can control the Tour playback speed by simply clicking the >> button on the playback controls in the bottom left of the view window.

If you'd like to actually change the raw speed in the KML, you can simply divide all Tour/Playlist element durations by some fixed number like 2.0.  Dividing by 2.0 will halve the playback time, resulting in playback that is twice as fast as realtime.